# Can different species of particles annihilate with other species

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter

Obviously electrons annihilate with positrons, but can a muon annihilate with an positron, or can an anti-taon cancel with a muon? similarly for quarks of different species, e.g. u and anti-strange.

I think this is possible as long as quantum numbers like charge and spin are conserved, with the excess energy being given off in kinetic energy, but has it ever been observed?

Comment: This has been addressed before [Does a particle annihilate only with its antiparticle? If yes, why?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7663/520), [Particle antiparticle annihilation-do they have to be of the same type?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14549/520), [More on matter and anti-matter](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9152/520), [What happens if we put together a proton and an antineutron?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18795/520) and perhaps one or two more.

Comment: @dmckee Thanks, your references to "Does a particle annihilate only with its antiparticle? If yes, why?" cleared completely my confusion. Also thanks to Anna.V and Marek for their explanations.

Answer (score 5):

There are more quantum numbers to be conserve than charge and spin. There is also lepton number and baryon number and strangeness and charmness and color for strong interactions.

A muon hitting a positron can interact exchanging a photon and keep going,   or a W and turn into a muon-neutrino and an electron-antineutrino through the week interaction .

Quarks are worse because they also have color, three extra quantum numbers plus charge  number (1/3 or 2/3) plus baryon number(1/3).

T[ake the pion](http://www.egglescliffe.org.uk/physics/particles/mkquark/quarks.html): pi+  is a linear combination of up anti-down and will eventually turn into a (muon+ anti-muneutrino) via the weak decay.

You may call it annihilation, as you may call all interactions where the incoming particles and the outgoing differ. The customary use of the term is for particle antiparticle annihilation.

It is more [complicated than](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/expar.html) you think.

Comment: "A muon hitting a positron can interact exchanging … a Z and turn into a muon-netrino and an electron-antineutrino" - and what about $\mu^-$ $\pi^+$ interaction?

Comment: it will have to conserve muon lepton number and could go to mu neutrino plus two photons, among other things. It is not called annihilation as not all quantum numbers are annihilated. It is not an experiment that can be carried out since both the muon and/or the pion would decay before encountering each other.

Comment: I've asked explanation of this reaction in terms of gauge  bozons.

Comment: a W- will be exchanged with the quarks making up the pion. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PiPlus-muon-decay.png . It is not really annihilation since the muon leptonic quantum number is conserved. One speaks of annihilation when all quantum numbers add to zero.

Comment: Maybe muon emits W-bozon and turns into muon-neutrino, pion absorbs W-bozon and turns into gamma? Then in muon-positron interaction muon emits W-bozon (not Z-bozon!) and turns into muon-neutrino, positron absorbs W-bozon and turns into electron-antineutrino. But what about gamma in the last case?

Comment: It is a turned diagram from the decay of a pion as shown in the link in my comment above. A W is exchanged (t channel diagram it becomes) wit the quark loop and a gamma comes out. The gamma or a gluon are necessary for the reaction to be physical, for momentum conservation.

Answer (score 0):

A few theoretical samples of  mixed annihilation (at low energy):

$e^- \mu^+ \to \gamma \; \nu_e  \bar{\nu}_\mu$

$\mu^- \tau^+  \to \pi^0  \nu_\mu \bar{\nu}_\tau$

$\mu^- \pi^+  \to \gamma \; \nu_\mu$