# Complete annihilation of matter-antimatter

Tags: antimatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More on matter and anti-matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9152/more-on-matter-and-anti-matter)

Everyone knows that when matter and anti-matter come in contact, they result in pure energy.
I want to know that if atoms and anti-atoms of two different elements are brought in contact, and one having much more charge and mass than the other..will it still result in pure energy because in this case equal amount of opposite charge is not present to counter each other.
Will it result in leftovers ?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9731/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14549/520 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19681/520 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7663/520 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9152/520 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18795/520

Comment: Please accept my apology for closing as a duplicate of the wrong question initially. Corrected now.

Comment: @dmckee nevertheless there exists a gross misunderstanding in the form of this question as "pure energy" is meaningless in the particle level, as well as the "more mass and charge" formulation.

Comment: @annav Well, yes. And some of the answers to the other questions I linked address those issues directly (and essentially all the answers address it indirectly). Was that a request to have this question re-opened, or just for aside?

Comment: @dmckee just to have it on record since closed questions if not deleted are there to be read. I also commented to John Rennie 's answer which I think is very superficial and hand waving.

Comment: @dmckee:it's ok ..I have no problem in question getting closed as long as I am getting answer by any source !