# What will happpen between a proton and an anti-neutron with unmatched color charges?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, color-charge

Maybe a stupid question because my search didn't return anything.

Assuming in low energy state, a proton (made by a red up, a blue up and green down quarks) meets an anti-neutron (made by an anti-green up, an anti-red down and an anti-blue down quarks). Will they stay together without annihilation because of unmatched color charges? Or gluons will be emitted to change colors so annihilation happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's commonly said that a nucleon contains three quarks, it's more accurate to say that the net number of quarks (i.e. number quarks - number anti-quarks) is equal to three. The interior of a nucleon is a fantastically dynamic place and the number of quarks and gluons at any instant is typically much greater than three.

So it is wrong to imagine the proton as containing *a red up, a blue up and green down quarks*. All you can say is that the net red charge, net green charge and net blue charge will all be one.

You comment *gluons will be emitted to change colors so annihilation happens* is sort of true, but it's a bit misleading to imagine there is, for example, a distinct down quark that is green and you need to wait for a gluon to be emitted before it changes colour. A better way of describing this would be to say the down quark is in a superposition of all colour charges.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me make sure that I really understand: I can't say for sure if this proton will annihilate with anti-neutron or not because color charges of quarks are governed by probability not certainty. I can only say it has a good chance to annihilate and find out by making an observation to collapse probability into certainty.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18795 and the links therein. The proton anti-neutron annihilation is slow by the stands of nuclear reactions, but always happens eventually.

Comment: A question somewhat related to this intriguing answer .. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/217371/changing-or-static-quark-color-composition-within-a-proton

Comment: Or in other words, those two baryons do not have unmatched color charges, they are both white.